# C# If statement point relationship

Tags: c#

I need help understanding the best way to for if statements to check whether your mouse is up, down,left or right of a starting point that you create. if you start the if statement with determining if the mouse is left or right of the starting point then you are always considered either left or right of the starting point because up and down are pretty much a strip of pixels because of the order the if statements are created.

What would be the best way to determine where your mouse is from a starting point?

Comment: I didn't understand the second sentence. What did you try and what's the problem with that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
bool isLeft, isRight, isUp, isDown;

if (startingPoint.x < mouse.position)
{
//left
    isLeft = true;
}
if (startingPoint.x > mouse.position)
{
//right
     isRight = true;
}
if (startingPoint.y < mouse.position)
{
//down
      isDown = true;
}
if (startingPoint.y > mouse.position)
{
//up
     isUp = true;
}
```

Then you can use the bools like this

```
if (isRight && isUp)
{
//upper right
}
```

or maybe something like this to give the mouse a little buffer area:

```
if (startingPoint < mouse.position - 1)
{
//left with buffer of one
}
```

There are several ways to achieve this. It's not difficult, and that is why people downvoted your question.

Comment: Isn't it the opposite? If `mouse.position > startingPoint.x`, then the mouse is right, not left. The same applies to up/down. I think you swapped the mouse position and the starting point in your logic.
On a side note, no need to check for the second and fourth conditions if the first and third are true; I'd add an else there to avoid this.

Comment: I was going from the perception of the starting point, but yeah, you get the point it seems. Sorry for the confusion.